# Trying to make a tar archive in bash script linux

Tags: bash

Im trying to make a bash script where you enter files/directories but every-time i get to the last part, it keeps saying-> tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive. Here is my script. The script works until it asks Should these files be compressed

```
#!/bin/bash

echo  "enter some files/directorys to be backed up:"

read $*

if [ -f $* -o -d $* ]
then
        echo $* its a valid file/directory

        echo "Where/which folder is the file stored??"
        read location

        if [ -d $location ]
        then
                echo "Its a valid location"
        fi

        echo "Should these files be compressed? (Y/N)"

        read ans

        if [ $ans = Y -o $ans = y ]
        then 
                sudo tar -czvf $*.tar.gz $*
                echo "success" 

        elif [ $ans = N -o $ans = n ]
        then
                sudo tar -cvf $*.tar $*
        fi
else
        echo $* invalid
fi
```

Comment: The line that starts with #!/bin/bash and the line that ends with else echo $* invalid fi is part of the script

Comment: What do you think `read $*` does?

Comment: Also, `-f` and `-d` do not work with multiple arguments. They test if exactly *one* file or directory name exists. (`-o` is not recommended at all; use `[ -f ... ] || [ -d ... ]` instead.

Comment: `$*` is a list of *multiple* arguments; you should not use it if it is were guaranteed to be a *single* argument. Use `$1` for that.

Comment: @chepner well i thought it was supposed to take multiple arguments (i forgot to mention im still learning linux)

Comment: And finally, run your script through shellcheck.net and fix any recommendations made there before asking your question.

Comment: No, `read` reads a single line of input and uses that to set the values of one or more variables. `$*` is already set as soon as you start your script, and `read $*` would attempt to use the values of those arguments as names of variables to set.

Comment: I actually didnt know that about the read. Thank you the site you mention seems pretty clear(im still reviewing it)

Comment: `sudo` is a command designed to allow the users without administrative rights to do certain administrative operations like adding/removing devices, creating users etc. Creating an archive is not an administrative operations. You don't need to use `sudo` for that. Even more, once you start using `sudo` for the usual activities you cannot escape. A file created using `sudo` belongs to `root` and you need to use `sudo` to edit it or to remove it. And so on, and so forth. Stop using `sudo` for non-administrative operations!